# WPF - draggable окна в окне

Tags: c#, wpf

В MS VS 2019 в главное окно состоит из встроенных окон ( возможно и не окон, а каких-то других объектов ).
Пример на скринах: [image: ОКНА]

Цветом обозначил объекты (окна). Данных объекты можно двигать, лепить к какой-либо части основного окна или оставлять отдельно, например на другом экране.
[image: ОКНА2]

Вопрос такой: как реализовать такой функционал в самом WPF? Какие использовать объекты, возможно есть встроенные в .Net классы или ещё чего.

P.S. Гугл не помог. Возможно не верно формулировал ,что хочу найти.

Comment: Хз актуально оно или нет, но когда то давно я использовал [Avalon dock](https://tym32167.blogspot.com/2011/12/avalonedit-avalondock.html?m=1)

Comment: `Гугл не помог. Возможно не верно формулировал ,что хочу найти.` - зовется это `MDI`.

Comment: tym32167  Спасибо,посмотрю.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо!